# How do you switch characters in Beast Arena?

Tags: beast-arena

I'm playing Beast Arena for Android and I'm in a stage where they let you have 4 characters as backup. All other users switch characters when the ones using are weak, but I only see a list where it displays them and if I click them nothing happens, also I don't see a switch button anywhere.

How do you switch characters in Beast Arena?